# TFS 2012 check-in/check-out

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

Given this scenario: Dev1 and Dev2 working on Lib.cs.  Dev1 checks in Lib.cs to TFS with his changes.  A week later Dev2 (w/o Getting Latest) checks in his changes to Lib.cs and is not prompted to fix conflicts.  I would assume that because Dev2 did not get the fix conflicts tab that TFS was able to merge the two files.  However, we see that Lib.cs was overwritten with Dev2 changes and it looks like no merge was attempted.

Could this be because Dev2 did not perform Get Latest more frequently?

Answer (score 2):

This most likely happened because Dev2 chose "Keep Local" when prompted about the conflicts. I have never seen a scenario where a merge by TFS would result in one persons changes would be lost, without user interaction. The Auto Merge facility is not designed to lose changes, ever.

The other scenario is that Dev2 did try to resolve the conflicts and just cherry picked the wrong bits.

Comment: what you described is the behavior i would have expected to see. after further testing i was able to reproduce this by making a Lib2.cs with the contents from Dev1 that were initially checked in to TFS and checked that in. i then replaced the contents of Lib2.cs with what Dev2 attempted to check in earlier and performed a check in to TFS. i was not prompted about any conflicts and the original content of Lib2.cs was replaced with Dev2 changes.